# Secure WCF service, what sort of authentication needed in addition to SSL protocol?

Tags: wcf, security, authentication, ssl, service

I have a server with SSL certificate and would like to implement a WCF service with username authentication. Can anyone point me to a simple current example?

I find lots that use the 509 certificate and I don't understand why that additional piece would be needed. I don't think I want to  give the certificate I have for the SSL to the client either.

I think to use SSL is just setting up the web.config appropriately with wshttpbinding and using https: in the uri that calls the service.

In this case I will have only one or two users (applications at the client actually) that need to use the service so I don't see the overhead for building a database for the store for lots of login credentials or anything like that. I've read you can pass the credentials in the request header. I hope I can just have the service itself check them without tons of overhead.

I'm really struggling to get how a simple authenticate can work for a service but I know I need something in addition to the service being SSL encrypted.

Edit: Hummm having read more I get the impression that using https binding for the message circumvents any notion of username credentials without something mysterious with certificates going on. I hope I haven't wasted money on the ssl certificate for the server at this point.

Can the IP of the requestor be used to allow the service for a known client only?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a couple of users, then use the inbuilt [Windows authentication](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/how-to-enable-windows-and-ntlm-authentication-on-wcf-service/) - create Windows user accounts, put the right security option in your binding config and you're done. If you're using SOAP from a non-windows client you'll have to perform some tricks to make it communicate properly (typically we found using NTLM authentication from PHP client required the use of curl rather than the PHP SOAP client library, but I understand that if you use AD accounts this becomes much easier).

[WCF docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff405740.aspx) have a full description of auth options for you.